# Visual Studio Code 1.0 x11 forwarding?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, command-line

Is anyone able to run code 1.0 over ssh w/X11 forwarding enabled?
https://code.visualstudio.com/

When I run it, nothing happens. No errors etc.

The --help isn't very useful.

I'm able to run other programs, like Firefox, fine.

Comment: Update: This works fine from a Linux environment. But if I ssh -XC from Windows (putty) with XMing, it doesn't work. But all other apps (like Firefox, gedit etc...) work fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is this not possible? Why only this app?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/840#issuecomment-252154908

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me if you're coming from a Windows machine:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40013437/3011683

User Frank Liu was nice enough to come back and answer his own question, which was to use VcXsrv rather than Xming.

Comment: Both yours and adamtheray's solution work for me – technically. Unfortunately VSC has an unusable high latency. Neither the ethernet connection nor SSH is at fault here: LibreOffice works great with Xming or VcXsrv. Possibly some of the added complexity of using a complete browser (Cromium) as the underlying framework might be the cause. It's quite a pity…

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it running by implementing a change on the libxcb libraries.

```
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

I was using CentOS so I changed it to:

```
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib46/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

Found the solution at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3451

Comment: I'm using the following start script for VSC which does not touch the global libraries `tempDir=$(mktemp --directory); cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 $tmpDir && sed -i "s/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/" $tempDir/libxcb.so.1 && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$tempDir code` (copied over by hand, hopefully doesn't contain typos).