# Visual Studio Code on Linux Xwindow forwarding

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

My configuration is as follows:

OS:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Visual studio code 
`1.5.3`

Xming `6.9.0.31`

I had to jump quite a lot of hoops to get [visual studio code](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) installed. At the end, I managed to do that. 
When I run

`code` or `code .`

It returns to the command line immediately with no error.

Then I ran

```
code --verbose
```

I get the following messages.

```
OpenGL Warning:
XComposite not found or old version (0.0), no VisibilityTracking
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/.config/Code/storage.json']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/vagrant/.config/Code/storage.json' }
(5:08:07 AM) ### VSCode main.js ###
(5:08:07 AM) /usr/share/code/resources/app { _: [],
  paths: [],
  performance: false,
  verbose: true,
  debugPluginHost: undefined,
  debugBrkPluginHost: undefined,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  goto: false,
  diff: false,
  extensionHomePath: undefined,
  extensionDevelopmentPath: undefined,
  extensionTestsPath: undefined,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  locale: undefined,
  wait: false }
```

Also, installing node.js didnt help. Xwindow forwaring works fine for other programs, such as ImageMagick, QtCreator. etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Xming doesnt have features that are needed by `vs code`. Installed [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! This was the solution for me as well!

Comment: Later version of XMing which you need to donate to get works fine

Comment: This is no longer the case. I am not able to get `code (1.22.1)` on Ubuntu 14 to run via `VxXsrv (1.19.6.4)`. Also see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35553.

Comment: I managed to run VS code 1.22.2 on Ubuntu 16.4 with xming 7.7.0.30 and with VcXsrv, the trick is to run it like this from the putty (or xmingrc menu): dbus-launch code. But code complains that "Linter pylint is not insalled", even i' sure it works normally if I run VS code from Team Viewer screen.

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to launch Visual Studio Code version 1.10.1 using Xming version 7.7.0.15.

Comment: Why did my answer get a downvote? I use Visual Studio Code every day with Xming version 7.X.

Answer (score 0):

XMing works for me! All defaults nothing changed except enable X11 forwarding in PuTTy.

Note however to get recent versions of XMing you have to donate on the [author's website](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) which will email you credentials to access the 7.x installs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it running by implementing a change on the libxcb libraries.

```
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

I was using CentOS so I changed it to:

```
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1
sudo sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' /usr/lib46/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

Found the solution at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3451